# Pyinstaller with FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory after added data

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller

I am trying to use pyinstaller to pack my application, but I met some problems. I developed software in venv environment, and my structure is like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZPIB.png)

func_a.py has read json file from resources like

```
with open('resources/requirement.json') as jsonfile: 
    request_Doc = json.load(jsonfile)
```

But I still got the error from pyinstaller

```
File "functions/func_a.py", line 15, in <module> 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/request_Doc.json'
```

However, I do add the json file in the spec.
I am wondering why func_a.py couldn't find the path of json file?

I try to put functions/*py, resources/*json and main.py in bin to pack but the problems still exists. What should I design my structure when developing the application like this?

==========================================> Edited on 2023.11.04

This is my project structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9ZhU.png)

This is how I write in py files
`func_a.py`

```
import json
import os
import func_b

with open('resources/requirement.json') as jsonfile:
    requirement = json.load(jsonfile)
    jsonfile.close()
jsonfile.close()


def func():
    if os.path.exists(requirement['token_path']):
        print('Get Token')
    func_b.go()
```

`requirement.json`

```
{
    "token_path":"resources/token.json"
}
```

`main.py`

```
import functions.func_a as func_a

f = func_a.func()
```

AND I try to use command pyinstaller main.py --add-data (resources/*.json, resources)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method as the issue can be that you're encountering is likely due to the fact that `PyInstaller` uses a different working directory when you run the bundled executable compared to when you run your code from the development environment.

Using `sys._MEIPASS` (For One-File Bundles):
When you create a one-file bundle with `PyInstaller`, you can use `sys._MEIPASS` to access files that are bundled with the executable. Here's how you can modify your code in func_a.py to load the JSON file:

```
import sys
import os
import json

# Get the path to the directory containing the bundled files
base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

# Construct the path to the JSON file
json_file_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'resources', 'requirement.json')

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as jsonfile:
    request_Doc = json.load(jsonfile)
```

This code checks if the script is running as a one-file bundle (created by PyInstaller) and uses `sys._MEIPASS` to locate the bundled files.

Using sys._MEIPASS2 (For One-Folder Bundles):
If you created a one-folder bundle with PyInstaller, you can use `sys._MEIPASS2` instead of `sys._MEIPASS`. The code remains mostly the same as the code above, but you replace `sys._MEIPASS` with `sys._MEIPASS2`:

```
import sys
import os
import json

base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS2', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

json_file_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'resources', 'requirement.json')

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as jsonfile:
    request_Doc = json.load(jsonfile)
```

Comment: Please upvote and mark it as a correct answer if it's correct and helped you qwq

Comment: thanks but it did not work and show the same error code 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/resources/request_Doc.json'
I am wondering how the path in the pyinstaller work?

Comment: I edited the original and tried to understand the issue now so please try it and let me know and also make sure files exists, the correct name/extension exists the dir is correct and everything

Comment: I think it works. But I still want to know what actually is the path inside the Pyinstaller. If I use --add-data (resources/*:resources) means I add all data in resources into a new folder in Pyinstaller root dir right (root/resorces/all data*) . Then why the main.py couldn't get the data with open json (resources/data)

Comment: I met another problem because I have many json files in resources folder. I the requirement.json is the path to store other json file path like {"ID":"resources/ID.json"} So the after using your method, I got error code say it couldn't find "resources/ID.json"

Comment: And what is the code for that part? where you handle the path? can you give full code for that part? I want to know what is the very end path in the end main func is getting. so please provide that code or an image

Comment: Already edited the structure of my code